# Выдает сообщение Oops! Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser!

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests


url = 'https://lolz.guru/market/steam/?vac[]=252490&order_by=price_to_up&buy=1'
headers = {
'accept': '*/*',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
source = req.text
print(source)
```

В чем проблема и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать `cookie` в `header` - сайт не принимает запросы без куки. И во вторых, нужно использовать библиотеку `requests-html`, обычный `requests` не может отправить запрос с включенным `JavaScript`

Comment: А можно пример кода с добавлением cookie? как их указать